# Why can´t I write char to String?

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32, arduino-esp32

```
#include <Preferences.h>
Preferences preferences;


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  char keyToAdd[15];

  String valueToAdd;

  keyToAdd = Serial.readString();
  valueToAdd = Serial.readString();

  preferences.begin("licence",false);

  preferences.putString(keyToAdd, valueToAdd);

  preferences.end();
 }

void loop() {
}
```

I want a key maybe "room" and want to write on my Serial monitor room test
but ...

What I got is this error:

```
incompatible types in assignment of 'String' to 'char [15]'
```

Answer (score 2):

`Serial.readString()` returns a `String` object, `keyToAdd` is an array of 15 characters. There is no automatic conversion from `String` to a `char` array.

I don't think you need a char array in this case anyway. Just make `keyToAdd` a `String` the same as `valueToAdd` then use `c_str()` to get a `const char*` to pass to `putString`:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  String keyToAdd;

  String valueToAdd;

  keyToAdd = Serial.readString();
  valueToAdd = Serial.readString();

  preferences.begin("licence",false);

  preferences.putString(keyToAdd.c_str(), valueToAdd);

  preferences.end();
}
```

Comment: readString times out quickly. Not too easy to handle, if you have two consecutive Serial.readString() calls

Comment: @datafiddler I'm not advocating this being the correct code (I've only occasionally dabbled in Arduino), I was just fixing the error in the question